# ELK logging in microservices architecture

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, microservices, elastic-stack

I am implementing centralized logging for all of my microservices using ELK. My doubt is whether I will have to create separate index for each microservice or a single index for all the microservices logs. My research so far shows that single common index for all the microservices make sense for centralized logging to achieve searches across microservices. Also I learnt that too many indices are a bit of overhead in elasticsearch. So I would like to hear from someone experienced

I have already this question in Software recommendations  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42338/elk-logging-in-microservice-architecture

Comment: A lot of it is going to be specific to your use-case. How many microservices are you talking? How much hardware are you able to dedicate to Elasticsearch? Is there a common log format that each of the microservices has? These are some of the basic questions you'll need to answer before really knowing how you want to segment the data. With the right index names and patterns in Kibana, you can still search across multiple indices, so I wouldn't consider separating data into index-per-microservice a hindrance in searchability.

Comment: @vase I am talking about some 20-25 microservices. I can dedicate an elasticsearch cluster with few highend machines. Yes there is a common log format across microservices. I also feel that the logs are really "centralised" when you can leverage searching across microservices. What is your take on this ?

Comment: As long as you have a common format and the data doesn't have any hard requirements for separating it, I would personally just throw it all into a single index (you can use the daily index rotation that Logstash provides by default) and monitor performance. If the Elasticsearch cluster can handle the input but searching is slow, you can increase the shard count per index or spread the data across different indices, perhaps based on logical contexts of the microservices themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In our scenario, we had 50+ microservices and we performed logging on basis of use-cases like UserManagement could be one use case consisting of several microservices(user, role, policies etc).

**So we had one index corresponding to one use-case.**

This way we leveraged efficiency in our reporting system because reports were around each use case like how many users logged-in and logged-out at what time, what were the changes in user role before and after etc.

Similarly you can create Elastic Index corresponding to another use case too.
This way we segregated the elastic index data and any downtime/re-indexing of any one index will not affect another index.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I don't understand why do you wanna index corresponding to use cases ? Because you can visualise in many forms from the indexed data based on use case right!